# x² function (0-3) to solve the Riemann integrate

Tags: functions

x² function (0-3) to solve the Riemann integrate the range
What is it that Mathematica code?
Please show me the steps

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4):

I thought perhaps the limit of a Riemann Sum:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

riemann[f_, {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ}, n0_?NumericQ] :=
  With[{n = Ceiling[n0]}, 
   With[{partition = Union[{a, b}, RandomReal[{a, b}, n - 1]]},
    With[{values = RandomReal /@ Partition[partition, 2, 1]},
     Differences[partition].f[values]  (* assumes f is Listable -- f /@ values is safer *)
     ]]];
NLimit[riemann[#^2 &, {0., 3.}, n], n -> Infinity]

(*  9.  *)
```

(That was fun.  No convergence warnings, at least the time I tried it.)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you want to integrate x^2 from 0 to 3?  If so it would be:

```
Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, 3}]
```

Comment: Yes thank you very much...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use equally sized intervals, you can do it symbolically (though [@Michael E2's approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98947/531) gives the full generality of the Riemann Sum and is generally cooler).

```
In[1]:= With[{h = (b - a)/n},
         Sum[h*(a + k*h)^2, {k, 0, n}]]
Out[1]= ((a - b) (1 + n) (a^2 - 2 a b + b^2 + 2 a^2 n + 2 a b n + 2 b^2 n))/(6 n^2)

In[2]:= Limit[%, n -> Infinity]
Out[2]= 1/3 (-a^3 + b^3)

In[3]:= Simplify[% == Integrate[x^2, {x, a, b}]]
Out[3]= True 

In[4]:= With[{n = 20, a = 0, b = 3}, With[{h = (b - a)/n}, 
          Show[Plot[x^2, {x, a, b}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3.2}, All}], 
              RectangleChart[Table[{h, (a + k*h)^2}, {k, 0, n}], 
               BarSpacing -> None]]]]
```

[image: Riemann sum]